# How to replace sub by mgsub and convert caracters

Tags: bash, gsub

I made a script which extracts text from multiple images but I do not success to do 2 things :

1 - I currently replace [\n] by a space but I have multiple strings to replace (let's say "a" by "b", "c" by "d" and "e" by "f"). I tried with mgsub without any success. Probably I do it wrong. Is that possible to help me on that ? Ideally, with a table at the begining of the script.

2 - In my "response.txt" output file, special caracters like "é" or "à" are "Ã‰" and Ã€ (seems to be in iso and not in utf-8). How to convert it ?

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
file=/home/freebox/input.txt
lines=$(cat ${file})
for line in ${lines}; do

   curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     --data "{
      'requests': [
        {
          'image': {
            'source': {
              'imageUri': '${line}'
            }
          },
          'features': [
            {
              'type': 'TEXT_DETECTION'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }" "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=mykey" | jq -r '.responses[0].textAnnotations[0].description | gsub("[\n]"; " ") | ascii_downcase' > cat >> response.txt
done
IFS=""
exit ${?}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: As for the file type, I've found a command called `iconv`. Good luck

Comment: Is the suggested solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

`jq` (1.5+) should be able to handle UTF-8 just fine.

`curl` however, doesn't convert the file encoding it retrieves. If the REST end point sends your response in latin1 (ISO8859-1) or similar you have to convert it yourself to UTF-8.  `iconv` is a handy tool for this job:

```
curl URL | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 | ...
```